# Merge & remove duplicates

Tags: mysql

We have a few MySQL (InnoDB) tables with repeated data and I want to clean them up. Consider the following:

Table `user_clubs`

```
| id | user_id | name                   | function                 | description         | school_grade |
|----|---------|------------------------|--------------------------|---------------------|--------------|
| 1  | 10      | World Cultures Club    |                          | Cultural activities | Freshman     |
| 2  | 10      | World Cultures Club    |                          | Cultural activities | Sophomore    |
| 3  | 10      | World Cultures Club    |                          | Cultural activities | Senior       |
| 4  | 20      | National Honor Society |                          | Vounteer            | Second Year  |
| 5  | 30      | National Honor Society | Public Relations Officer | School Society      | 11th         |
| 6  | 30      | National Honor Society | Public Relations Officer | School Society      | 12th         |
| 7  | 40      | Student Council        | Sophomore Secretary      |                     | Sophomore    |
| 8  | 40      | Student Council        | Junior Secretary         |                     | Junior       |
```

We have duplicated rows for each school_grade. What I want to end up with is:

- Remove the `school_grade` column, having all the `school_grade` values in a `user_clubs_meta` table
- Remove unnecessary duplicates in the `user_clubs` table, keeping only the record which has a related `user_clubs_meta` record

Example:

- record id `1,2 & 3` need to get reduced to a single row and a new `user_clubs_meta` row with `meta_key=school_grades` and `meta_value=["Freshman","Sophomore","Senior"]` needs to get added (id column omitted for simplicity)
- id `4` can be left as-is
- id's `5 & 6` needs to get consolidated & meta added
- id's `7 & 8` can be left as-is

Where I need help:

- Populate the `user_clubs_meta` table. I have the following query:

  ```
  INSERT INTO user_clubs_meta (user_clubs_id, meta_key, meta_value) 
  SELECT id, 'school_grades', CONCAT('[', GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('"', school_grade, '"')), ']')
  FROM user_clubs 
  GROUP BY user_id, name, function, description 
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
  ```

  Data looks good to me, but I'm not 100% positive if this gives me the correct result. If someone could confirm.
- Remove the duplicate records from `user_clubs`. This is where I'm completely stuck. I guess basically do the opposite/diff of

  ```
  SELECT id
  FROM user_clubs 
  GROUP BY user_id, name, function, description
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
  ```

  where the query would give me only a list of id's which I can remove from `user_clubs` unless the record has a related record in `user_clubs_meta`.

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: Why `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` in the first query? Do you want to create meta data entries only for duplicated `(user_id, name, function, description)` combinations?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Well, no, for all of them unless the `school_grade` value is empty. I guess for the moment leave the `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query for populating the `users_club_meta` table looks good to me except for two issues:

1. I am not entirely convinced about `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`. If you want to create entries for all combinations of `(user_id, name, function, description)`, remove that condition.

   If you want to omit the groups consisting only of empty `school_grade` values, you can use this condition instead:

   ```
   HAVING COUNT(school_grade) > 0
   ```

   That is assuming that by "empty" you mean NULL. If you mean to exclude empty strings (`''`) as well, you could modify the above condition like this:

   ```
   HAVING COUNT(NULLIF(school_grade, '')) > 0
   ```
2. You are selecting `id` in that query but the column is not in GROUP BY. It is true that MySQL allows you to do that but the [manual also discourages](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) that you do that in cases where the non-aggregated non-GROUP BY column has multiple values per group.

   If you want predictable results, use an aggregate function, for instance MIN():

   ```
   INSERT INTO
     user_clubs_meta (user_clubs_id, meta_key, meta_value) 
   SELECT
     MIN(id),
     'school_grades',
     CONCAT('[', GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('"', school_grade, '"')), ']')
   FROM
     user_clubs 
   GROUP BY
     user_id, name, function, description 
   HAVING
     COUNT(school_grade) > 0
   ;
   ```

For the DELETE query, take the final draft of the INSERT statement's SELECT query keeping only `MIN(id)` in the SELECT clause and removing the HAVING clause:

```
SELECT
  MIN(id)
FROM
  user_clubs 
GROUP BY
  user_id, name, function, description
;
```

That gives you the first ID of every unique combination of `(user_id, name, function, description)`. That will be the rows you want to keep. All the others you want to remove. This is an anti-join, and there are various ways to implement it. In this case you can go with:

- `NOT IN`:

  ```
  DELETE FROM
    user_clubs
  WHERE
    id NOT IN
    (
      SELECT MIN(id)
      FROM user_clubs 
      GROUP BY user_id, name, function, description
    )
  ;
  ```
- `LEFT JOIN` + `WHERE IS NULL`:

  ```
  DELETE
    uc
  FROM
    user_clubs AS uc
    LEFT JOIN
    (
      SELECT MIN(id) AS min_id
      FROM user_clubs 
      GROUP BY user_id, name, function, description
    ) AS filter
    ON uc.id = filter.min_id
  WHERE
    filter.min_id IS NULL
  ;
  ```

The left join method is known to work fast in MySQL but you should test for yourself in your environment to choose what works better for you.

Comment: Thanks, you rock! Just a note for future readers: If you use MariaDB, the DELETE query will throw an error: `Table '_table_' is specified twice, both as a target for 'DELETE' and as a separate source for data`. Fix: double wrap the subquery like so `DELETE FROM user_clubs WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT MIN(id) FROM user_clubs GROUP BY user_id, name, function, description) ids);`. [MariaDB:Subquery Limitations](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/subquery-limitations/)

Comment: Ah yes, I think that can happen in MySQL proper too, at least I think I've heard something like that in the past but forgot about it when writing the answer. Thanks for the reminder.